# Installing windows 7 on Inspiron 14z hybrid hdd/ssd

Tags: windows-7, ssd, windows-installation, hybrid-storage, msata

So the copy of Windows 8 wont boot on my Inspiron 14z Ultrabook, I don't have a recovery disc, and don't want to wait for Dell to send me a new disc. I think I'd rather have Windows 7 anyways.  I have a copy of Windows 7 and I'm trying to install it but I want to ensure that the hybrid hdd/ssd (500GB 5400 RPM SATA HDD and 32GB mSATA SSD) will work when I'm done installing.

So when I get to the part where I select the partition to install the drive I see the following:

```
Name                        Total Size  Free Space  Type
Disk 0 Part 1: ESP          500 MB      447 MB      System
Disk 0 Part 2: DIAGS        40 MB       35 MB       OEM (Reserved)
Disk 0 Part 3               128 MB      128 MB      MSR (Reserved)
Disk 0 Part 4: WINRETOOLS   500 MB      220 MB      OEM (Reserved)
Disk 0 Part 5: OS           450.9 GB    317.2 GB    Primary
Disk 0 Part 6: PBR Image    13.7 GB     261 MB      OEM
Disk 1 Part 1               8 GB        0 MB        Primary
Disk 1 Unallocated Space    21.8 GB     21.8 GB
```

1. So should I delete all of the Disk 0 partitions, format them as one and then install?  Are there any partitions I should leave for functionality like hibernation?
2. What do I do about Disk 1 (SSD)?
3. How do I ensure that the SSD portion is setup correctly and working?
4. The SSD portion of the drive is just supposed to work like cache for the HDD right?

EDIT: I should add that even though I've worked as an IT pro in the past, I have absolutely no experience when it comes to these types of drives and Win8.

Comment: backup the Win8 image on an external drive and yes, kill all partitions on disk 0. To use the SSD as cache, follow this: http://superuser.com/a/568719/174557

Comment: @magicandre1981 do you mean I should backup all the partitions on Disk 0 or just the OS partition? What would you recommend I use to backup it up?  I'd rather not remove the drive to back it up with another PC if I can help it.  Also, you might want to include this as an answer so you can get credit. Thanks.

Comment: Dell provides a software to backup the HDD (Dell Backup and Recovery). You should do this for the case that setup of Win7 fails and that you can go back to the original state.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I can't even get it to boot.  How do I create recover discs if it wont boot?  I can't even run the win 8 refresh because it says the HDD is locked.

Comment: should i install windows on the ssd?

Comment: what happens when you try to boot Win8? Boot from the DVD->repair options and let Windows try to fix issues.