# How to confirm that my SSD running as cache correctly?

Tags: windows-8, ssd

I am using HP Workstation laptop, with a SSD as cache. I have installed a new Windows 8 on my laptop. 
There is nothing related to the SSD from software side so far I know, so I cannot know did my Windows 8 recognize the SSD and use it as cache? 
Any suggestion is welcome.
 Thank you very much

Comment: make sure **Intel Smart Response** is configured correctly: http://superuser.com/a/568719/174557