# "Lost" caching SSD

Tags: windows, hard-drive

Went early July from Windows 8.1 pro 64 bit on a 2013 Dell to 10 pro 64 bit smoothly, preferences came over w/o a glitch. Comes the most recent set of updates, OK mostly except for lost printer default (went to XPS), lost file associations & minor stuff. Used machine for several days without problems.

Comes Thanksgiving morning (how ironic), won't boot - bad BCD file. Apparently some update didn't complete. Got a Win 10 pro 64 bit from a pal (I only have the one PC). Tried recovery, update in place leaving own stuff, fresh load - nope.

Did a fresh load to another partition on the 2 GB & got 10 back but lost Intel RST drivers and can't defrag any 2GB vol (unavailable).

Have a working machine but can't figure out how to reinstall the SSD drivers. Any thoughts welcome - I considered separating the disk & SSD && placing pagefile/swapfile/hibernation files on it (only 32GB) but the disk & SSD are
integrated (wired togather).

Comment: Welcome, please try to keep your questions as concise as possible. Dropping the overfamiliar tone will help. If you got error, include it word-for-word.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a configuration where the SSD is configured as a buffer device for the HDD. That's why it is not separately addressable.

SSDs also do not require any specific drivers.

If you want to move specific files to an SSD, I recommend you purchase a additional SSD. SSDs are relatively cheap these days.

Comment: the SSD cache requires a driver/setting. this is called Intel Smart Response: http://superuser.com/a/568719/174557