# Instead of SSD, found HDD

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, ssd

I bought a ASUS laptop and it is mentioned that disk is 256 SSD.
After buying when I checked I found the following, not why it is mentioned hard disk drive.

Insight is highly appreciable.

[image]

Update 1

Using a tool called Speccy, I have the following information about storage, not sure about what is mentioned about hard disk in above picture

[image]

Comment: Yup, your added info makes it look like you got a hybrid drive, not a 'pure' SSD. As it isn't 256GB but 1TB, it's definitely not what you ordered, even allowing for some confusion factor. [downvote retracted]

Answer (score 1):

The operating system can't necessarily tell the physical substrate of a storage device that's connected to it, so it refers to them all as "hard disk drive" because if it said "block-structured data storage device" it would confuse people and take up too much space. If your laptop is supposed to have an SSD, it's 99% likely that you do in fact have an SSD.

Comment: I have update my question, could you have a look?

Comment: OK, that does look like a hard drive _and_ a (small) SSD, and you should query it with whoever you bought the laptop from.

Answer (score 1):

According to what you've shown Speccy is reporting, you have a [24GB Kingston SM100 mSATA SSD](http://www.os-store.com/kingston-ssdnow-ms151-24gb-ssd-sms151s3-24g-mini-pci-e-msata-hdd-mlc-6gb-s-hard-disk-solid-state-drive-module-laptop-30x50mm.html) and a [1TB HGST Travelstar 5K1000](https://www.hgst.com/products/hard-drives/travelstar-5k1000) 2.5" Hard drive (not SSD).

Comment: Could you provide more insight as what does 24GB SSD can be used for? Can I use for virtualisation? or does it help when I have a virtual pc with another OS?

Comment: You can use the 24GB SSD for anything you need to store (that takes up less than 24GB. :) )

Answer (score 1):

The small SSD is used as cache to the slower HDD. This is called [Intel Smart Response](https://superuser.com/a/568719/174557). In this case the SSD is hidden from Windows and this is why you only see the HDD.