# Is my SSD cache supposed to say 0 MB formatted?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, ssd, hard-drive-cache

I have a Lenovo ideapad Y510p, which has lost A LOT of its speed over the last year. I recently did a full format and reinstall of Windows 10, but the effects were not as good as I hoped.

Then, recently, I discovered that my SSD cache is showing "Formatted: 0 MB" in task manager. Might that be the reason?
I don't want to format the SSD disk and risk messing it anymore up, if I'm not sure that it's not supposed to be like that.

[image]

Comment: I just checked, all my SSD say Formatted = Capacity. So this is *uncommon*

Comment: All of those are a little odd... My SSD is formatted = capacity, system disk = yes and page file = yes. Not sure on what your actual set up is, but it doesn't sound right.

Comment: Thanks. And those are caches, right? This is not my main disk.

Comment: Apologies - I misread the question. Mine is configured as the boot drive. What have you used to configure the drive as a cache? It's possible that, as it may not be formatted in a standard Windows format, task manager doesn't interpret it correctly and reports it as such.

Comment: you have to activate the **Intel Smart response** feature again, to use the SSD as cache for the HDD : http://superuser.com/a/568719/174557

Comment: I tried that. The SSD was not available for activation in the Intel software. I have found my solution, though. See my answer in a couple of seconds. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my speed problems. The solution was to install ExpressCache. The SSD is now listed the same way in task manager as in my original post, however, it is used by ExpressCache much like the Intel Rapid Storage Technology would do.

See more here: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/Guide-ish-Windows-10-Upgrade-Y510p/m-p/2168135/highlight/true#M131461