# SSD to make system faster

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, operating-systems

I own a laptop which has a 1TB HDD and a 25GB SSD to fasten the OS.

If I'd wipe that HDD, would the SSD still be used for this purpose?
Or how can I set it to behave this way? Is it set only for the preinstalled Windows system, or works for all systems?

Comment: Windows using the SSD has a cache, is something you do at the system configuration, if you wipe the HDD you would have to configure Windows to use it as a cache yourself.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/568719/174557

Answer (score 0):

25GB? That is extremely small for even just a boot drive.
A cache might work, but it will not give you the huge boost you're looking for.