# Deleted the SSD part of my SSHD (Hybrid HDD) accidentally

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid, cache, hybrid-storage

I accidentally deleted my SSHD's SSD partition. It's connected as RAID. I don't know why, but one day it was shown like AHCI (still RAID in BIOS settings). I thought it was my 16GB flash drive and I deleted it in Ubuntu.

My main OS is Windows 10 and I don't know if my SSHD is working properly (SSD caching). Is there a way to understand if it is caching in SSD like I did that mistake before?

Comment: SSHDs don't have a separate volume for the SSD component that is accessible to the end user. Something doesn't add up here. Do you perhaps have a drive with two volumes, i.e. not an SSHD?

Comment: @Twisty https://i.hizliresim.com/013D8V.jpg and https://i.hizliresim.com/P0jMpb.jpg

Comment: okay I've managed thanks to @magicandre1981 but I get this error 0xa001004e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! It's a possible duplicate like @magicandre1981 said, I've done everything in this link [Why is my Hybrid Disk not Active?](https://superuser.com/questions/568674/why-is-my-hybrid-disk-not-active) but there was an extra error for me: 0xa001004e

I am using Intel® Rapid Storage Technology 14.8.0.1042 version. Only this version is working properly for me